# finding length of union array

Tags: java, arrays, union

I am trying to find length of an array formed by union of two arrays. I can print out the union elements like this, but have no idea how to get length of my union array. Any ideas?

Can it be count variable length of my union array?

```
    int[] array1={1,3,2,5};
int[] array2={4,5,1,3,2};

int m = array1.length, n = array2.length, k = array1.length, i = 0, flag = 0;

int c[] = new int[m + n];
int d[] = new int[m];

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    c[i] = array1[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (array2[i] != array1[j]) {
            flag = 1;
        } else {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        c[k] = array2[i];
        k++;
    }
}
int count = 1;
for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
    count++;           
}
int p = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (array2[i] == array1[j]) {
            flag = 1;

            break;
        } else {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        d[p] = array2[i];
        p++;
    }
}
System.out.println("The length of the union array is: " + count);
```

Comment: Why not just do `array1.length + array2.length` ?

Comment: @ThomasEdwin, that will not work if there is common element in 2 arrays.

Comment: it will be 9, but the union array is {1,2,3,4,5} with length of 5.

Answer (score 2):

The count should be `k + m` and not `k`. So just replace:

```
for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
```

with

```
for (i = 0; i < k + m - 1; i++)
```

Better solution would be to assign `k + m` to `count` and print it. Something like this:

```
count = k + m;
System.out.println("count is " + count);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a unique count then use `Set`:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));

count = set.size();
```

Comment: `array1={1,3,2,5}, array2={4,5,1,3,2}, set =[1,2,3,4,5]`. count will be 5.